# Downloaded Bitcoin core from Github, getting configure error: (configure: error: libdb_cxx headers missing)

Tags: macos, homebrew, headers, bitcoin

I'm following along with Andreas Antonopoulos Bitcoin book [Mastering Bitcoin](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032281.do)
**Chapter 3 (The Bitcoin client)**

I'm on a Mac and used homebrew to install the dependancies:

```
brew install autoconf automake libtool boost miniupnpc openssl pkg-config protobuf qt
```

Next step was `./autogen.sh` which created some configuration scripts

Now stuck at the configure script step. After running `./configure`, everything looks good until the last line which is:

```
configure: error: libdb_cxx headers missing
```

How do I get libdb_cxx headers installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah figured it out, I didn't completely finish reading all the instructions in the build-osx.md file

````
#### Installing berkeley-db4 using Homebrew

The homebrew package for berkeley-db4 has been broken for some time.  It will install without Java though.

Running this command takes you into brew's interactive mode, which allows you to configure, make, and install by hand:
```
$ brew install https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Formula/berkeley-db4.rb -–without-java 
```

These rest of these commands are run inside brew interactive mode:
```
/private/tmp/berkeley-db4-UGpd0O/db-4.8.30 $ cd ..
/private/tmp/berkeley-db4-UGpd0O $ db-4.8.30/dist/configure --   prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/berkeley-db4/4.8.30 --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/berkeley-db4/4.8.30/share/man --enable-cxx
/private/tmp/berkeley-db4-UGpd0O $ make
/private/tmp/berkeley-db4-UGpd0O $ make install
/private/tmp/berkeley-db4-UGpd0O $ exit
```
````

After exiting, you'll get a warning that the install is keg-only, which means it wasn't symlinked to `/usr/local`.  You don't need it to link it to build bitcoin, but if you want to, here's how:

```
$ brew --force link berkeley-db4
```